# Script for selectively deleting directories by date

Tags: linux, bash, debian, sh, file-management

I'm running an sh script on my debian machine. It's done nightly and uses rsync to create incremental backups. It saves each backup in directories named by date. so i have:

```
2015-07-01
2015-07-02
2015-07-03
2015-07-04
and so-forth
```

What I would like to be able to do is delete old copies as the list grows. Preferably I'd like to keep daily backups for the past week, and weekly backups for as long as i have space.

Which means I need to do two things:

1. Check the date of each folder name. If the date is not a Saturday, and is older than 7 days, Delete it.
2. Check the amount of used space on this partition (/dev/sdb1) and delete the oldest folder if the disk usage is above 75%.

I'm thinking that step 2 would need to be in a loop perhaps. So that it can delete one backup at a time. Recheck the space available, and delete another folder if we're still above the 75%.

I'm assuming all this is possible with bash scripts. I'm still very new to them. but from what I've found whilst googling around it should be pretty straight forward for someone who knows what they are doing. I'm just having trouble figuring out how to piece the elements together.

Comment: For the 1st, I would suggest to make the Sunday's directory name little different (for example `2015-07-01-weekly`) and then use something like `find /backup -name '????-??-??' -mtime +7` to remove the old dirs.

Comment: haven't tried ccollect. rsnapshot was fine. It seemed to work well enough. But it lacked as much customization as I'd have liked. it seemed to be limited on folder naming scheme. I want folders with dates. also I don't think it has features for deleting backups based on disk space. etc. I may not know much bash script now, but I won't learn it if i don't try either.

Comment: You definitely should better use rsnapshot. It creates incremental backups using rsync an rotates them with the nice shcheme by renaming. By default it keeps 6 daily backups, 3 weekly backups and so on. You can also configure it and extend it with your scripts for specific targets.

Comment: @user3132194 But is rsnapshot able to do both of my tasks in the way I want? I know it does daily, weekly, monthly, but can it be configured to name by date and not just "daily 02"? And can it delete by disk usage? I already know how to make rsync do more than what rsnapshot can do. So why wouldn't I just use rsync? If rsnapshot can do those would you be able to help me figure out how to set it up for that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my old [script](http://pastebin.com/q1LgqsLw), which i do not use after i have migrated to rsnapshot. It have some hardcoded strings, but i hope you could modify it for your needs. Also it measures free space in gigabytes, not percents. With rsnapshot i do not need it anymore for my purposes.